# Quake on 32 bit Ubuntu 17,04

Tags: games

Where do I get Quake's game-data-packager for Ubuntu 17.04?  I have a 32 bit computer.  I have installed Quake I.

Answer (score 0):

`game-data-packager` is in the 17.04 repos.

```
user@pcname:~$ apt-cache policy game-data-packager
game-data-packager:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 49
  Version table:
     49 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/multiverse amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/multiverse i386 Packages
```